# Find the correct data structure

Tags: database, data-structures

I need to store around 10 millions strings that are around 500 characters long each.
I'm on AWS so can use the available structures.

My usecases are as follow :

- Read/Write an element from multiple client
- Store unique elements
- Check if it contains a specific element

And either :

---

- Get a random element
- Delete a specific element
  (This way I would delete it from a first structure and put it in a second structure of the same kind)

OR

- Maintain a boolean property "processed"
- Get a random element that satisfy this property

---

At first, I though of using a queue or something similar, as new strings are continuously coming, but queues doesn't allow for uniqueness check and random access.

Most databases I checked don't satisfy the "get random element" function and seem a bit overkill for my usecase as I only need one or two columns.

I've been also thinking of deploying a service through node and manage it with javascript arrays. But I'm not sure about the "check if it contains a specific element" function with so many elements in the array.

Comment: *"don't satisfy the "get random element"*" - with Postgres you could do a `select * from the_table tablesample (1) limit 1`

Comment: Talking about your first use case, does your requirement allow minor approximations? Or can you bear false positives? You can checkout [HyperLogLog data structure of Redis over here](https://redis.io/commands/pfcount)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thanks, I didn't know about this functionnality of postgre !

Comment: @DhruvilsinhVaghela From what I read, HyperLogLog is to compute aggregate, right ? I'm interested about retrieving a specific element (i.e. a specific string to know if it is present or not or know it's state) but not counting anything.

Comment: @Romain Add element and check cardinality. If unchanged, element already existed.

Comment: @DhruvilsinhVaghela Thanks, I never thought about using Redis and finally came to use the "set" data structure in Redis. This perfectly fits my needs !

Comment: @Romain I’d suggest you post your solution as an answer so it can be referenced further by someone in need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally chose to use Redis Set data structure. It doesn't guarantee that the same property won't be read by 2 differents clients at the same time. But it allowed to query randomly while maintaining a property on my value.